# Altering one element's position with the hover state of another

Tags: css, hover, siblings

I have a css triangle positioned under one of two buttons that indicates the text below it is associated with that button. When I hover over the button next to it, I would like to move that triangle to under the second button.

My triangle is a an empty div with the following styling:

```
.nubbin {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 2em solid transparent;
  border-right: 2em solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 2em solid #435C6E;
  margin-left: calc(50% - 10em);
}
```

My buttons have classes of, "report and class". What I've tried is:

```
.chat:hover~.nubbing {
  margin-left: calc(50% + 10em);
}
```

and

```
.chat:hover+.nubbing {
  margin-left: calc(50% + 10em);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you post your HTML and/or a link to a demo please?

Comment: also, might just be a type here on SO but nubbin != nubbin*g*

Comment: You are better off associating the triangle with the button itself. Check out ::before or ::after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like ralph.m mentions, you're better off the using ::after pseudo element.

Check out this example:
http://jsfiddle.net/scottmey/PhZ7x/2/

Hopefully this points you in the right direction.

```
.comment {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 620px;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    background: #435C6E;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.comment:hover:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: -15px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px 15px 10px 0;
    border-color: transparent #435C6E;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Also worth mentioning browser support, IE7 this is unsupported.